# If package depends on `lubridate`, `dplyr` and other of `tidyverse`, which shall I list as dependency?

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen

I'm developing a package that uses function from `lubridate`, `dplyr` and some other packages of `tidyverse` family. Which should I put in my `DESCRIPTION` file?

Answer (score 1):

List only packages whose functions you use in your library. In particular, the tidyverse package appears to be a collection of packages, and you should not list it as a dependency.